# I have 2 queries in SQL Server; when the first query executes, then after 5 minutes I want to execute the second query

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 queries in SQL Server. I want to execute the first query, and then wait 5 minutes before executing the second query.

Comment: you should try WAITFOR clause

Answer (score 3):

Something Like this-

```
----Delay for 5 min
Select 'Query 1'
WAITFOR DELAY '000:05:00'
SELECT '20 Second Delay'
GO
```